# Recyclerview with many viewholders

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, view

Help please fix adapter for recyclerview. It must just add all objects from list to  recyclerview (as list).

code:

Adapter:

```
public class TestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

    private Context context;
    private List<Model> listItems;

    TestAdapter(Context context, List<Model> listItems){
        this.context = context;
        this.listItems = listItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        switch (listItems.get(position).type) {
            case 0:
                return Model.YOUR_MESSAGE_TYPE;
            case 1:
                return Model.INTERLOCUTOR_MESSAGE_TYPE;
            case 2:
                return Model.ADVERTISING_INTEGRATION_TYPE;
            default:
                return -1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view;
        switch (i) {
            case Model.YOUR_MESSAGE_TYPE:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.your_message_item, viewGroup, false);
                return new YourMessageVH(view);
            case Model.INTERLOCUTOR_MESSAGE_TYPE:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.interlocutor_message_item, viewGroup, false);
                return new InterlocutorMessageVH(view);
            case Model.ADVERTISING_INTEGRATION_TYPE:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.advertising_integration_item, viewGroup, false);
                return new AdvertisingIntegrationVH(view);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        Model object = listItems.get(i);
        switch (object.type) {
            case Model.YOUR_MESSAGE_TYPE:
                Picasso.get().load(object.getImage()).into(((YourMessageVH) viewHolder).image);
                ((YourMessageVH) viewHolder).message.setText(object.getMessage());
                ((YourMessageVH) viewHolder).date.setText(object.getDate());
                ((YourMessageVH) viewHolder).message.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "CALLBACK TO Activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                break;
            case Model.INTERLOCUTOR_MESSAGE_TYPE:
                Picasso.get().load(object.getImage()).into(((InterlocutorMessageVH) viewHolder).image);
                ((InterlocutorMessageVH) viewHolder).message.setText(object.getMessage());
                ((InterlocutorMessageVH) viewHolder).date.setText(object.getDate());
                break;
        }
    }


    private class YourMessageVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView image;
        TextView message;
        TextView date;

        private YourMessageVH(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_your_image);
            message = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_your_message);
            date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_your_message_date);
        }
    }

    private class InterlocutorMessageVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView image;
        TextView message;
        TextView date;

        private InterlocutorMessageVH(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_interlocutor_image);
            message = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_interlocutor_message);
            date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_interlocutor_message_date);
        }
    }

    private class AdvertisingIntegrationVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        Button button;

        private AdvertisingIntegrationVH(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.b_show_reward);
        }
    }
}
```

list data:

```
public class Data {

    public static ArrayList<Model> getModelList() {
        ArrayList<Model> list = new ArrayList<>();

        String date = "18.04.2019";
        String johnSnowImage = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/901947348699545601/hqRMHITj_400x400.jpg";
        String ygritteImage = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/c/c4/Ygritte-Rose_Leslie.jpg/220px-Ygritte-Rose_Leslie.jpg";

        Model yourFirstMessage = new Model();
        yourFirstMessage.setType(Model.YOUR_MESSAGE_TYPE);
        yourFirstMessage.setImage(johnSnowImage);
        yourFirstMessage.setMessage("Игритт, подожди!");
        yourFirstMessage.setDate(date);
        list.add(yourFirstMessage);

        Model interlocutorFirstMessage = new Model();
        interlocutorFirstMessage.setType(Model.INTERLOCUTOR_MESSAGE_TYPE);
        interlocutorFirstMessage.setImage(ygritteImage);
        interlocutorFirstMessage.setMessage("Ничего ты не знаешь, Джон Сноу!");
        interlocutorFirstMessage.setDate(date);
        list.add(interlocutorFirstMessage);

        Model yourSecondMessage = new Model();
        yourFirstMessage.setType(Model.YOUR_MESSAGE_TYPE);
        yourFirstMessage.setImage(johnSnowImage);
        yourFirstMessage.setMessage("Кое-что я знаю. Знаю что люблю тебя. Знаю что ты меня любишь. Но сейчас мне нужно домой!");
        yourFirstMessage.setDate(date);
        list.add(yourSecondMessage);

        Model firstAdvertisingIntegration = new Model();
        firstAdvertisingIntegration.setType(Model.ADVERTISING_INTEGRATION_TYPE);
        list.add(firstAdvertisingIntegration);

        return list;
    }

}
```

Example:

Recyclerview must show up "yourFirstMessage" then "interlocutorFirstMessage" then "yourSecondMessage" and then "firstAdvertisingIntegration" (all this object from Data)

But its show up like "yourSecondMessage" then "interlocutorFirstMessage" then empty cardview block and then "firstAdvertisingIntegration".

Sorry for english.
Hope you can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to make that by yourself. 
Here is an open source library for you, It's powerful and easier to use.

https://github.com/CymChad/BaseRecyclerViewAdapterHelper